# Using Worksheet_SelectionChange (ByVal Target As Range) for a specific column starting from E12

Tags: excel, vba

I have a form that users are required to fill up.

`Cell E5` contains a drop-down list for users to select an option. However, users may insert new rows below `Cell E5` if they have more than one users to add to their submission (i.e. one row, one user).

I was wondering if it is possible to so-called add-on to my target range under Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range). So if user inserts a new row, the drop-down list and formatting I did for `Cell E5` will also be the same for the next row which the user has inserted. Any help is truly appreciated..this is the code I have thus far:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)

'''I have tried If not intersect(Target, Range("E")) is Nothing then .....but it has not been working out
'''I think I saw one with r + 1 etc.... but I'm not too sure how to go about that

If Not Intersect(Target, Range("E5")) Is Nothing Then

Dim col As New Collection
Dim rng As Range
Dim i As Long
Dim DVList As String

For Each rng In Sheet2.Range("A1:A5,C1:C7")
   If Len(Trim(rng.Value)) <> 0 Then
        On Error Resume Next
        col.Add rng.Value, CStr(rng.Value)
        On Error GoTo 0
    End If
Next rng

For i = 1 To col.Count
    DVList = DVList & col.Item(i) & ","
Next i

With Sheet1.Range("E5").Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, _
    AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, _
    Formula1:=DVList
End With
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I'm not too sure what you're after, but based on your title do you not want to use something like `If Target.Column = 5` (column E), and `Target.Row >=12` (from row 12)?

Comment: I think I understand what you're asking.  If you want each new row to look and act like the original row, then that can be done.  I don't see how you are adding rows though.  Do you rely on the user to insert the row themselves?

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious firstly, thank you for understanding what I'm saying cause I'm bad at putting my thoughts down into words. And yes, exactly as what you said, i want the new row to act like the original row if users insert a new row below `Cell E12`

Comment: @Dean hey dean, sort of but I only want this to happen for the new rows inserted by the users

Comment: How are the users creating the row?  If they can choose any method then you are in a very difficult position. It is probably easier to prompt the user and add rows for them instead of trying to handle all the possible scenarios. For example, if they create a row before populating E5 then you can modify your existing code to work when E5 it is selected for entry; but that won't work if they populate E5 before adding a row.  What if they add more than one row? What if they don't add a row, instead they cut from row 6 to the bottom of the form and paste the section 3 rows further down?

Comment: hmmm I will put an instruction that asks them to insert their rows by clicking on Cell A13 for example. So it would have something to do with if `Range("A13").insert shift := xlshiftdown then` ........ but that code doesnt work for me..

Comment: @ProfoundlyOblivious after much consideration to what you said, what if I want to copy the whole code format of `Cell E12` to `Cell E13` if the user fills in `Cell B2`? Instead of allowing them to insert new rows, I am putting in a fixed table for users where there can only be a max of 10 records. So if they fill in Col B12:B21 then that counts as new user records. Hope what I'm saying is making sense..

Comment: _"copy the whole code format of Cell E12 to Cell E13 if the user fills in Cell B2?"_ Certainly doable and easy.  You would use the worksheet change event as the trigger - you're using selection change right now. [ms documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change)  It would be  helpful if you can post a picture of your template, it seems odd to only be concerned with one cell after inserting a row.  Have to head to work so it will be a while for me to update.